# Spring Security. Как, в зависимости от роли пользователя, выполнить разные методы при запросе на адрес?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Идет запрос на адрес. Нужно, в зависимости от прав пользователя, выполнять разные методы.

---

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/currentAsset",method = RequestMethod.GET)
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('MANAGER')")
public Map<String, List> currentAssetManager(Model model){
    Map<String, List> stringListMap = new HashMap<>();
    //logic
    return stringListMap;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/currentAsset",method = RequestMethod.GET)
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('BOSS')")
public Map<String, List> currentAsset(Model model){
    Map<String, List> stringListMap = new HashMap<>();
    //logic
    return stringListMap;
}
```

этот вариант не работает, какое аналогичное решение
Spring 3.0

Comment: Покажите, что уже сделали.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995744/spring-security-mvc-same-requestmapping-different-secured

Comment: Вот неплохой ответ на ваш вопрос:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021200/how-to-check-hasrole-in-java-code-with-spring-security

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уточните версию Spring-Security которую вы используете. В Spring-Security 3.0 есть класс [SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/servletapi/SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.html#isUserInRole(java.lang.String)) который позволяет определить наличие той, или иной роли. В вашем случае в контроллере можно использовать что то вроде

```
if(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.isUserInRole("admin")){
   //Некоторые действия
}
else {
   //Некоторые действия
}
```